# blanks issue within COUNTIFS()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to establish a conditional formatting rule using COUNTIFS() that highlights entire rows when all cells within a certain row matches all cells within another row.

Heres what I've got so far which seems to work when there aren't blanks in my data set:

```
COUNTIFS($E$25:$E$500,$E25,$F$25:$F$500,$F25)>1
```

However, when there are blanks found, the function returns 0 and nothing is highlighted.

Are there ways around this exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[COUNTIFS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

> If the criteria argument is a reference to an empty cell, the COUNTIFS
> function treats the empty cell as a 0 value.

But empty cells in a range do **not** equal a 0 value. So they are not counted.

To get both in same type context you can try:

`=COUNTIFS($E$25:$E$500,$E25&"",$F$25:$F$500,$F25&"")>1`

The concatenation of an empty cell and an empty string results in an empty string rather than a 0 value. That works using Excel 365.